# When I drag and drop multiple files into VS Code, I have to click on them one by one for them to load. How can I make them load automatically?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to drag and drop a bunch of files to open, and immediately find and replace on all of them simultaneously using the search menu in the sidebar. When I do so right now, the files aren't loaded and I have to click on each tab for them to load. I'm on macOS in case that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been [a](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68570) [handful](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64411) [of](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80648) [bug reports](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182899) on this, [where dragging files into VS Code and trying to immediately search them doesn't work](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/62488). A workaround would be to open a new window, drag a folder from Finder containing the files you want to search, into the window, and then open the search menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you add <kbd>./</kbd> in *Auszuschließende Dateien* it will only search and replace in open files.

[image: Search and replace in open files]

Comment: I think you misunderstood my issue. I want all the files I drag and drop into VS code to automatically load, without having to click on each of them one by one. Find and replace is why I want to do that.

Comment: If I drag and drop several files from the Finder, they are all automatically opened.

Comment: I just restarted my Mac, and they do not automatically open for me when dragged from Finder.

Comment: Are you dropping them on the right in the editor window, not on the left in Explorer?

Comment: Yeah I was doing that. However, when I drag them to the explorer sidebar (it only works when I have at least one file open), they don't automatically load then either.

Comment: By the way, when you drag let's say, 5 files into VS code, can you immedately find and replace on all 5 files in the sidebar? Without having to click on all the other tabs?

Comment: I don't understand what is still unclear. Opening files via drag & drop shouldn't be a problem, searching via the open tabs works as described in my answer. So yes, I can search through these tabs (without having to click on all other tabs).

Comment: I came back to the issue and I'm still having it, I posted a video here demonstrating the issue, can you look at it? https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/13ic602/help_i_never_got_an_answer_for_how_i_could_have/